# Add / delete a div based on selection in multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I want to add or delete a particular div:

here's the div

```
<div class="quantity form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="dept">Quantity:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="number">
</div>
```

Based on a particular selection from the following select tag:

```
<div id="selection" class="form-group ">
<label for="sel1">Select Items:</label>
  <select name="assets" class="asset-selection form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="asset1">Asset 1</option>
    <option value="asset2">Asset 2</option>
    <option value="asset3">Asset 3</option>
    <option value="asset4">Asset 4</option>
    <option value="asset5">Asset 5</option>
  </select>
```

I'm using select2 currently, and here's the script tag:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.asset-selection').select2({
  maximumSelectionLength: 5
});

$('.asset-selection').change(function(){
 //I'm not sure what to add here
}

 })

});

</script>
```

Now let's say `asset1` is selected from `.asset-selection`, I'd want `.quantity` div with an incremental id to be displayed.

Comment: Why not just use the .show() and .hide() methods in jQuery on the divs you want to... show or hide? I'm no jquery expert, but I believe it is $('#idNameOfDiv').hide(); that you are looking for

Comment: @GeorgeDaniel Hey, I appreciate your help, but what I want is _creation_ of divs, not showing/hiding. As in, when a particular asset is selected, _then_ its quantity is to be taken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is code for dynamic creation and deletion of quantity div with unique name based on selection of assets select2.

```
<div class="append_elements">

    </div>
 <div id="selection" class="form-group ">
      <label for="sel1">Select Items:</label>
        <select name="assets" id="assets" class="asset-selection form-control" multiple="multiple">
          <option value="asset1">Asset 1</option>
          <option value="asset2">Asset 2</option>
          <option value="asset3">Asset 3</option>
          <option value="asset4">Asset 4</option>
          <option value="asset5">Asset 5</option>
        </select>
        </div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#assets").select2();
  $('#assets').change(function(){
    array = $('#assets').val();
    if(array.length > 0){
        $(".append_elements").html('');
        array.forEach(function(key,entry) {
            var name = 'quantity_'+key;
           $(".append_elements").append('<div class="'+name+' form-group col-md-3"><label for="'+name+'">Quantity '+key+':</label><input class="form-control" type="number" name="'+name+'" id="'+name+'"></div>');
        });

    }
    else{
        $(".append_elements").html('');
    }

  });

});

</script>
```

Comment: worked! thank you! pretty neat solution. i had been lost in code :P

Comment: could you please explain the forEach function? I'm new to jQuery/javascript

Comment: It is simple , In forEach each element of array will be come and we are creating div element with unique name and append to our desire div(append_elements).

Comment: This solution 1. hits the DOM a bit more than needed, 2. Unnecessarily creates a global variable `array =....`,  3. changes the original "5" maximum 4. IF something were to happen in an input, (someone changed the value) it is not retained as you replace everything every time.

Comment: As requirement is to create and delete div dynamically based on selection of select2, this solution is working perfect. And array is no global variable.

Comment: I beg to differ `array = ` DOES create a global, it is hoisted to `window.array`

Answer (score 0):

Check single/multiple and see the results.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 // The next line is in comment to make this code run, uncomment it in your code that include the matching library.
  //$('.asset-selection').select2({maximumSelectionLength: 5});
  function hide_all_elements() {
   $(".asset").hide();
  }
  $('.asset-selection').change(function(){
   let className = $('.asset-selection').val();
    $.each(className, function (i, v) {
     className[i] = "." + v;
    });
    hide_all_elements();
    $(className.join(",")).show();
  });
  
  hide_all_elements();
});
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<div class="asset asset1 form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="dept">AAA:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="number">
</div>

<div class="asset asset2 form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="dept">BBB:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="number">
</div>

<div class="asset asset3 form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="dept">CCC:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="number">
</div>

<div class="asset asset4 form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="dept">DDD:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="number">
</div>

<div class="asset asset5 form-group col-md-3">
  <label for="dept">EEE:</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="number">
</div>

<div id="selection" class="form-group ">
<label for="sel1">Select Items:</label>
  <select name="assets" class="asset-selection form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="asset1">AAA</option>
    <option value="asset2">BBB</option>
    <option value="asset3">CCC</option>
    <option value="asset4">DDD</option>
    <option value="asset5">EEE</option>
  </select>
```

Comment: It would be better to use select2 to illustrate given the OP's requirement how that comes into the mix here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this may work. Code is a little funky but tweak to your liking. You may want to find another way to identify which option was clicked and a different method for "incrementing?" the Id attributes.

Note the `remove()` and `insertAfter()` methods because your question asked how to add or delete DOM elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let dynamicDiv = '<div class="quantity form-group col-md-3"><label for="dept">Quantity:</label><input class="form-control" type="number"></div>';
/*
    $('.asset-selection').select2({
        maximumSelectionLength: 5
    });
*/
    $('option').on('click',function(e){
        let currentOption = $(e.target).val();
        $('.quantity').remove();
        $(dynamicDiv).insertAfter('#selection');
        $('.quantity').attr('id',currentOption);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selection" class="form-group ">
    <label for="sel1">Select Items:</label>
    <select name="assets" class="asset-selection form-control" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="asset1">Asset 1</option>
        <option value="asset2">Asset 2</option>
        <option value="asset3">Asset 3</option>
        <option value="asset4">Asset 4</option>
        <option value="asset5">Asset 5</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: On a second selection of the multi-select, prior divs are removed?  Using a "click" may mean select or unselect but it adds it anyway?

Comment: Original post: "I want to add or delete a particular div:" I assumed that's what he wanted

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss well if you click the same html option tag twice, inherit behavior is to keep it selected, if you click a different one then the previous one is deselected in lieu of the current selection

Comment: BUT, this is `multiple` thus shift-select will pick multiple which is where this breaks down.

Comment: You are right, I didn't notice that property. I suppose that'd make sense why he'd want an incrementing id for the divs

Answer (score 0):

Using some select2 stuff and importantly a 'data' attribute with the value, you can add and file those by creation of a class with the amount value (I assume an integer data "amount" here, it is just a placeholder really)

I made this pretty verbose so you could see what is going on, you can compact it down.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.asset-selection').select2({
    maximumSelectionLength: 5
  });

  $('.asset-selection').on('select2:select', function(e) {

    var data = e.params.data;
    //console.log(data);
    let ma = $('#myassets');
    let sel = $(e.params.data.element);
    let ndiv = $('<div class="quantity form-group col-md-3"></div>');
    let nlabel = $('<label for="dept">Quantity:</label>');
    let ninput = $('<input class="form-control" type="number"/>');
    let amt = sel.data('amount') * 1;
    ninput.val(amt);
    ndiv.addClass('asset-number-' + amt);
    ndiv.append(nlabel);
    ndiv.append(ninput);
    ndiv.appendTo(ma);
    //console.log(amt);
  }).on('select2:unselect', function(e) {
    let ma = $('#myassets');
    let sel = $(e.params.data.element);
    let amt = sel.data('amount') * 1
    let removeme = ma.find('.asset-number-' + amt);
    removeme.remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/css/select2.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.5/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<div id="selection" class="form-group ">
  <label for="sel1">Select Items:</label>
  <select name="assets" class="asset-selection form-control" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="asset1" data-amount="1">Asset 1</option>
    <option value="asset2" data-amount="2">Asset 2</option>
    <option value="asset3" data-amount="3">Asset 3</option>
    <option value="asset4" data-amount="4">Asset 4</option>
    <option value="asset5" data-amount="5">Asset 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="myassets" class="container"></div>
```

Comment: NOTE: While I used a `.data("amount")` here, you could also use the select2 data and some property of that instead.  i.e. https://select2.org/programmatic-control/events